# How do I calculate and show frequency in an animated graph in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have some code which uses opencv to calculate movement and I graph it to time. I have a video of beating heart cells which gives me peaks every time the heart cells contract which I could turn into frequency like this.

[image]

I only have 2 weeks of programming experience and made my current code looking at multiple tutorials and mashing code together. I'm happy with what I have so far, but now I'm completely lost and don't know where to start. Here is my code up to this point.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=30,detectShadows=False)                     

plt.ion()

x_len = 60
y_range = [-2, 10]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
xs = list(range(0,60))
ys = [0] * x_len

line, = ax.plot(xs, ys, color='k')

ax.set_ylim(y_range)

plt.title('Movement over Time')
plt.show()

def animate(i, ys):
    ys.append(average)
    ys = ys[-x_len:]
    line.set_ydata(ys)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ys,), interval=60, blit=False)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('Masked', fgmask)

    average = (np.average(fgmask))

    print(average)

    plt.pause(0.00001)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: do you mean how to [display text on graph](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) ? You may also need `remove()` to remove all text before you put new one.

Comment: do you know how to recognize local maximum value ? Value which has lower values on the left and the right ? Then you can count frames between two  maximum values - every frame takes 60ms (`interval=60`) so frequency (per minut) should be `(60s*1000)/(number_of_frames*60ms)`

Comment: @furas Currently I do not know how to make the code recognize maximum values but I will look into it. I also didn't know what the interval parameter did exactly so thank you for explaining it. I will look into your method and try to implement it.

Comment: `interval=60` means that animation will draw new frames every 60ms. If you have three values and middle value is the highest (so you have lower values on the left and on the right) then you have local maximum. So if you will always remember last three values then you should recognize maximum